# Add a automatic slide option to jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, slider

I intend to use [this slider](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/demo/square-slider/) in a website but it doesn't have the auto play option. It just slides on mouse click event.

The jquery is as:

```
(function($){

    $('.square-slider').each(function(){
        var slider = $(this),
            slides = slider.find('.slide'),
            currentSlide = 0;

        slides.show();
        $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
        $('.next,.prev', slider).show();

        $('.prev', slider).on('click', function(){
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide--;
            if(currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        $('.next', slider).on('click', function(){
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide > slides.length - 1) currentSlide = 0;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

What shall i add to enable it auto slide from one image to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is trigger next button click event at periodic time.

**Example**

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.next').trigger('click');
},2000);
```

**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/LVfdj/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

wrap these code in a function like :

```
function next() {

slides.removeClass('active');
currentSlide++;
if(currentSlide > slides.length - 1) currentSlide = 0;
$(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');

}
```

then you can make use of javascript's `setInterval()` function like :

```
setInterval( next(), 5000);
```

That way, the next() function will execute every 5 seconds.

Comment: thanx, can you please provide a demo or just make the above suggestion a part of the code i mentioned. I really am new and can not figure how to call next function.